# Monolithic + MicroServices

Tags: microservices, backend

Right now I need to know exactly how can I instantly deploy a micro service based backend when needed? I can manage all the integration of technologies by myself but when it comes to hosting on AWS its just impossible for me to get those many instances and it is just impossible to afford right now.

Im contemplating on the idea of starting with a monolithic backend while having the possibility of deploying micro services backend instantly when the business kicks off.

But Im not sure how to achieve this idea if ever it is possible.

Is it possible or am I wrong?

Please help, thanks.

Comment: No, maybe like 2 separate projects achieving same goal but monolith project will be used first then when there is a good success I can switch to micro services. I dont know whether this is possible or makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common issue if planing to use Aws EBS, I had same issue and solved using following approch

1) Think design as monolithic and then decide further into bounded context and each bounded context will be a microservicea.

2) Now design your database and try to keep.each microservice db into separate schema.

3) Now in maven module create parent child module .

4) In parents module keep your spring boot main method, swagger,and common module like security etc

5) Disable spring boot nature in child module .

6) Add all child module microservice into parent module and maven build install.

7) Deploy on AWS EBS .

8 ) Expose all microservice using Aws Api getway.

Benefits: in future whenever you will be able to support infrastructure cost just move module and db schema and no other changes required.

Disagreed with  statement that "wrong perception that deploying monolithic is cheaper than micro-services" plz check Aws cost estimations monolythic is cheaper then microservice ,microservice need polygot persistence and independent hosting.

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/estimating-aws-resource-costs/
- https://calculator.aws/#/

Comment: I dont know anything about "spring boot". Im going to use GoLang, Node.js, Cassandra, Mysql, Redis, HAProxy, NGinX. Can you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it is a wrong perception that deploying monolithic is cheaper than micro-services w.r.t. infrastructure..If you are sure you want to go micro-services way; then its better to build it now..

You can build multiple micro-services and deploy on same virtual machine.
Also, these days you have many light weight technologies ( lighter than spring boot ) which has lesser memory footprint, faster start up time like micronaut.

Also, until and unless you are running at scale of Amazon... it is a wrong perception that monolithic cannot scale..Even monolithic can handle quite good number of requests.

Comment: "You can build multiple micro-services and deploy on same virtual machine." -------- So using this approach I can dedicate a virtual machine for each micro service easily when I get too much traffic later?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me clear my confusion and kill my headache which was there from 20+ days. Now I know what to do.

Comment: Its easy in the case of micro services run by different languages too?

Comment: Disagreed with statement  that "wrong perception that deploying monolithic is cheaper than micro-services"  plz check Aws cost estimations monolythic is cheaper then microservice ,microservice need polygot persistence and independent hosting.

Comment: @vaquarkhan it depends on case to case basis.. if u deploy both micro-service on same VM; then cost is same w.r.t. infrastrature.. why u disagree ?

Comment: @vaquarkhan I got the same question as Deepak.

Comment: Poligot persistence means each microservice need separate database if using same db then it will be distributed monolithic, each db instance has cost so deploy app host  and db will cost more in microservices

Comment: Distributed tracing log analysis ,health check , Cicd pipline all cost ,nothing is free

Comment: @vaquarkhan yes u are right in most cases that is true.. But even in databases; suppose on same MySQL Server you can create different schemas for each microservice and then whenever u want to scale u can easily migrate these schemas to different physical servers

Comment: @vaquarkhan but still with micro-services u will have to run multiple JVM which MIGHT need a bigger machine..

Comment: @Deepak "but still with micro-services u will have to run multiple JVM which MIGHT need a bigger machine.." ----- So the conclusion is to get multiple instances for each microservice or forget the project as price for both approaches is almost the same?

Comment: @vaquarkhan "but still with micro-services u will have to run multiple JVM which MIGHT need a bigger machine.." ----- So the conclusion is to get multiple instances for each microservice or forget the project as price for both approaches is almost the same?

Comment: @vaquarkhan What you would have done if you were in my place?

Comment: I am runing my two startup Java project on same design ,planing to move kubernetes soon, nodejs or go also you can use same design ,future is microservice so try to decouple ur app. You can find all details on following link 
 https://github.com/vaquarkhan/microservices-recipes-a-free-gitbook/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I would like to conclude this discussion by saying that if u eventually want to go to microservices then do it now..  "increase in infra cost will be  minimal if any".. Changing the codebase is not easy at later phase

Comment: @vaquarkhan I was only demotivated going for micro services when I looked at the cost involved. But according to Deepak the infrastructure cost would almost the same so I will go with the microservices with cheapest instance first.


 BTW I noticed in your bio on github "Technology Architect", could you tell me what is the difference between a Technology Architect and a Solutions Architect?

Comment: https://diceus.com/technical-architect-vs-solution-architect-vs-enterprise-architect/

Comment: let me put it simply.. They are just the same thing.. I have used them interchangeably..  All of them means that you are good in technology; and can design complex system; aware of ALL technologies

Answer (score 2):

I feel like building micro services from day 1 is the best approach these days, no one knows which of your services goes viral. You can not afford a blackout when everyone wants to connect to your services.

Comment: I agree with Ekatarina, its very wise to build micro services from the beginning to avoid rebuilding everything from scratch later.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible to build multiple micro-services and run on the same server / vps and when your project / service goes viral over-night you can always dedicate a separate instance / server for each service easily.